# Excel Pivot Chart - % Of Two Values

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-tables

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CORP | COAST | CITY | DONE | MISSING | TOTAL
-------------------------------------
New  | West  | LAX  | 2    | 4       | 6
Old  | West  | SFO  | 3    | 3       | 6
New  | East  | NYC  | 4    | 2       | 6
```

I make a pivot table that looks like this:

```
                   CORP:
COAST:             NEW | OLD
-------------------------------------
EAST                   |
  SUM OF TOTAL    | 6  |
  SUM OF DONE     | 4  |
  SUM OF MISSING  | 2  |
WEST
  SUM OF TOTAL    | 6  | 6
  SUM OF DONE     | 2  | 3
  SUM OF MISSING  | 4  | 3
```

I want to now add a `ROW` that is the percentage `DONE` of the `TOTAL` amount. I.e. something like this:

```
                   CORP:
COAST:             NEW | OLD
-------------------------------------
EAST                   |
  SUM OF TOTAL    | 6  |
  SUM OF DONE     | 4  |
  SUM OF MISSING  | 2  |
  % DONE          | %67|
WEST
  SUM OF TOTAL    | 6  | 6
  SUM OF DONE     | 2  | 3
  SUM OF MISSING  | 4  | 3
  % DONE          | %33| %50
```

The formula for `% DONE` is `DONE / TOTAL`

I've tried adding another `DONE` field to the pivot table (i.e. `SUM OF DONE2`) then setting the value to be `% OF`, the base field `TOTAL` and the base value `(previous)` however that makes `% DONE` return the value of `#N/A`. I've tried various combinations of the above however all are returning the same `#N/A`. I.e. my pivot table is looking like this:

```
                   CORP:
COAST:             NEW | OLD
-------------------------------------
EAST                   |
  SUM OF TOTAL    | 6  |
  SUM OF DONE     | 4  |
  SUM OF MISSING  | 2  |
  % DONE          |#N/A|
WEST
  SUM OF TOTAL    | 6  | 6
  SUM OF DONE     | 2  | 3
  SUM OF MISSING  | 4  | 3
  % DONE          |#N/A| #N/A
```

I've tried Googling how to do it but still to no avail. Please let me know if what I am looking for is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Analyze tab, add a Calculated field with the formula

```
 = 'DONE'/'TOTAL'
```

[image]

There is an option in Pivot Table Options that allows you to show blank if there is an error, so you don't get an N/A for old/east. You can go into field settings and format the field as a percentage.